# Socket works the for a few seconds then fails

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I've managed to establish a connection using socket. It works great for the first few seconds after that it runs super slow takes like almost 2-3 mins to complete a request. And then it produces this error continuously. The app doesn't crash it just runs slowly with the error displaying countless times.

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=9S6kqHJdHHXQgrobAAHp..
```

[Error on console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giEOg.png)

Main.js

```
    function Home(props) {
      const [Username , setUsername] = useState("")
      const [SearchedData, setSearchedData] = useState() 
      const [Data, setData] = useState()
      const socket = io('http://localhost:5000')
      React.useEffect(() => {
        // socket.current = io('http://localhost:5000')
        socket.emit("content","yada")
        socket.on("get-data", data => {
          setData(data)
        })
      })

     function NavBar(props){
        const handleClick = (e) => {
        const {id} = e.target
       if(id === "Post-btn"){
          if(Content.length > 0){
              let data = {
                Username: "yada", Content
              }
              props.socket.emit("store-data", data)
            } 
          }

           return(
              Tags....
              )}

function Content (props) {
        const onLike = (e) => {
        const { id } = e.target.dataset
        const data = {
          username: "yada",
          id : id
        }
        // console.log(data)
        props.socket.emit("like", data)
      }
    return(
     Tags.....
     )
}
```

server.js

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoDB,
 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(() => {
     console.log("Database Connected")
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
 });

const server = app.listen(process.env.Port, () => {
    console.log("Connected on " + process.env.Port)
})

const io = socket(server, {
    cors:{
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        credential: true,
    }
})

let cuid;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("content", username => {
        Comments.find({},(err, data) => {
            if(!err)
                socket.emit("get-data", data)
        })
    })

    socket.on("store-data", data => {
        const {Username, Content} = data 
        const newdata = new Comments({
        userName: Username,
        content: Content,
        createdAt: new Date().toDateString(),
        replies: []
    })
        newdata.save().then(data => {
                for(const d in data)
                 if(d === "_id"){
                    Users.findOneAndUpdate({username: Username}, {$push: {UserContent: data[d]}}, {new: true}, (err, save) => {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err)
                    else
                        console.log(save)
                })
            }
        })
    })
    
    socket.on("like", data => {
        const {username, id} = data
        Users.findOne({username:username}, (err, data) => {
          if(!err){
            cuid = data['id']
            console.log(cuid)
            Comments.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {score: data['_id']}}, {upsert: true}, (err, d) => {
              if(!err){
                  console.log(d)
              }
            })
        }
    })

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code provided, I noticed there is an useEffect without params. This may be causing a loop until the application crashes.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // socket.current = io('http://localhost:5000')
  
  socket.emit("content","yada")
  socket.on("get-data", data => {
    setData(data)
  })
  
  socket.on("Updated", data => {
    setData(data)
  })
}, []); <- this is missing
```

This empty array indicates that the content inside the useEffect will only run once.

More about this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Tried it.. Didn't work... Thanks But do you really think it's because it's in a continuous loop??

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: useEffect withouts dependencies are not recommended, "If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument"

Comment: I've managed to fix the crashing part.. But the problem is thats it runs slow takes a lot of time to process a request and once it does process it takes more time to get the data on the client side and it displays the error repeatedly.

Comment: Another suggestion I would make is, isolate your code to only run the socket part without the database, so you can verify that the problem is only on the socket layer and not in the db layer. Remove for testing purposes the calls and connection to the DB and return fixed messages from the socket layer